# Document height percentage of original height

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'd like to reset the height of the original document to remove extra space after elements are added.  The code I have now is this.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var document_height = $(document).height();
       document_height = 0.70 * document_height;
       $(document).height(document_height);
    });
```

This should change the document height but doesn't.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the original question does work.  Something else was adding more space to the document.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to be using `$(window)` in place of `$(document)`.

`$(document)` refers to height of the entire document, `$(window)` refers to the viewport size.

If you do indeed want the behavior for reducing height of the document object, you might consider alternatives in CSS to remove the margin/padding that is the "extra space" after the elements are added.

Comment: $(document) is what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think you are.  Document refers to the **entire** document; including the `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`.